# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

here i wanna run this code for try neural network with python :

```
from __future__ import print_function 
from keras.datasets import mnist from 
keras.models import Sequential from 
keras.layers import Activation, Dense 
from keras.utils import np_utils 
import tensorflow as tf


batch_size = 128 nb_classes = 10 nb_epoch = 12

#input image dimensions img_row, img_cols = 28, 28

#the data, Shuffled and split between train and test sets (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows * img_cols)

X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_row * img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32') X_test = X_test.astype('float32') X_train /= 255 X_text /= 255

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape) print(X_train_shape[0], 'train samples') print(X_test_shape[0], 'test samples')

#convert class vectors to binary category

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)

Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(output_dim = 800, input_dim=X_train.shape[1])) model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) model.add(Dense(nb_classes)) model.add(Actiovation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy']) #crossentropy fungsi galat atau fungsi error dipakai kalo class biner



#model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_poch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose = 0) print('Test Score : ', score[0]) print('Test Accuracy : ', score[1])
```

at the beginning it must install keras, and success. but when try to run the code at the first the error is :

> ImportError : No Moduled Name "tensorflow"

then i install using pip :

> pip install tensorflow

after installation i try to run code again, got another message like this :

> ImportError : No Moduled Name "tensorflow.python"

[Message Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYgfR.png)
i dont have any idea with the error

Comment: Is it this one: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2885

Answer (score 42):

Uninstall tensorflow:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Then reinstall it:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: Hi @zhaozheng would you be able to explain as to why this occurs; in the original `tensorflow`, why is the `tensorflow.python` not properly installed with it.

Comment: Not sure if I should be happy or sad that this actually worked

Comment: same with me , this method even worked for me even though my error was different :)

Comment: This 'works' because you most likely had a gpu based tensorflow installed before. By uninstalling and reinstalling you just changed that to cpu. Since there are other dependencies for gpu support, it had issues, now you don't face those issues because it is "downgraded" to cpu.

Answer (score 3):

for me upgrading `pip` helped,

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: If the above does not help, you can try installing non-cached tensorflow by adding `--no-cache-dir` to the last code line.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in Windows 10. Until now I don't know why.

But if I create an virtual environment

`cd <your project path>`

Install virtualenv

`pip install virtualenv`

Create the virtual environment

`virtualenv <envname>`

Activate the env

- Windows Powershell: `.\<envname>\Scripts\activate`
- Unix with Bash or zsh: `source <envname>/bin/activate`

Then now you install tensorflow

`(<envname>) $ pip install tensorflow`

And then run Hello World successfully.

*Don't forget that you need to activate or configure everytime the virtual environment jupyter, command-line, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have python 3.6 and up (most likely), a pip3 package will be installed by default. Installing tensorflow using pip3 will make the path of the installation visible to python. So try

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

First response ever, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running a python file named tensorflow.py, after renaming it the issue dissapeared and the file started running properly.

Answer (score 1):

Installing tensorflow 1.15 solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Open a python shell and type:

```
help('modules')
```

This will gather a list of all available modules. tensor flow should not show up, as it is not installed correctly (according to the `traceback`).
Then:

```
import sys
sys.path()
```

This will give you a list of system paths where modules can be installed. If there is a known issue with installing a module, I recommend moving the files manually to the right system path.
The system path depends on the OS you are using, so without knowing that I can't tell you where to move it.
But `sys.path()` can!

Comment: My tensorflow is in `help('modules')` list.

Comment: executing sys.path() gives this error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` I think it should be `sys.path` as it is not a method

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your file name to something unique. Apparently the python script with same name exits inside, this is the one thats causing the issue.
I was using my script, was working fine with bert_base_tf_20.py but when i changed the name to code.py , this happened. So changed it back to bert_code.py

Working fine

Answer (score 0):

There's another problem which is not mentioned here, and took me a bit to figure out. If you have python installed on `C:\Program Files\Python`, when installing tensorflow, pip will default to another directory. Removing python from `C:\Program Files\Python` and installing it in another directory such as `C:\Python` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me reinstalling with

```
 tensorflow==2.5.0
```

using pip worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

This worked for me

Answer (score -2):

try to change the actual running python directory.
and make sure that running python directory is not where you downloaded tensorflow. else go to any other directory and you're fine.
i hope that solves your probleme.

Answer (score -2):

try these steps

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: The OP mentions in the question they have installed tensor flow with pip this answer is not helpful