# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'; 'tensorflow' is not a package

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Problem:**

I install `keras` and `tensorflow` correctly. Although both of them installed but i encounter with the following error when `import keras`:

```
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/DeepLearning/paper/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keras.activations
  File "/home/saeed/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/saeed/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/home/saeed/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/home/saeed/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/saeed/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'; 'tensorflow' is not a package
```

**My efforts:**

I try these solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568913/tensorflow-import-error-no-module-named-tensorflow), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415629/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-python) but no result found. Also uninstall `keras` and `tensorflow` and install again but useless.

Where is the problem?

> **System**: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
>
> **Python**: 3.5
>
> **Keras**: 2.2.2
>
> **Tensorflow**: 1.10.0

Comment: How did you install keras and tensorflow? Pip install or pip3 install?

Comment: @PallaviJog Thanks for your answer: `pip install`

Comment: Try pip3 install.. it will install library for python 3x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Python3+, I would use `pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0`

`from tensorflow.keras import <whatever-module-you-need>`

Tensorflow is the Keras API. You could import from either!

Answer (score 1):

`Pip3 install` command instead of `pip install` should solve the problem.