# import tensorflow returns ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'; 'tensorflow' is not a package

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am trying to import Tensorflow from within PyCharm.
My Python version is 3.10 and tensorflow version is 2.8.
What could be the cause of the error?

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and returns

```
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'; 'tensorflow' is not a packag
```

[image: python version]
[image: tensorflow versi]

Answer (score 0):

Please verify:

1. make sure that both python and tensorflow are installed in the same path where you are trying to execute py folder/code.py [python and OS are 64 bit]

2.ensure you are not using file name as csv.py which already exist in python library.
2. pip uninstall tensorflow and then pip install tensorflow==2.7 stable version then run help('modules') you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415629/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-python)

Similar issues: [reference1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34722,)
[reference2](https://www.pythonpool.com/no-module-named-tensorflow-error-solved/)